# Error when starting virtualbox after ubuntu update

Tags: command-line, drivers, apt, kernel, virtualbox

After I updated ubuntu yesterday, when I try to start my virtual computer (whonix) in VirtualBox it gives me an error message:

```
Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with `/dev/vboxdrv`. Please install `virtualbox-dkms` package and load the kernel module by executing
```

So i searched for some information and found:

> As the first step run this command:
>
> ```
> sudo modprobe vboxdrv
> ```
>
> If it's not helpful run these commands:
>
> ```
> sudo apt update
> sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r) virtualbox-dkms dkms
> ```
>
> Then reboot your system and after reboot run this command:
>
> ```
> sudo modprobe vboxdrv
> ```

I wrote command in terminal : `sudo modprobe` , this said I can't find this command or something simular.

So I updated and installed/reinstalled and now when I try to start whonix, it doesn't give me an error message anymore. But the computer freezes every time when starting up, and I have to restart the computer by holding down the power button.

Now when I write the command: sudo modprobe vboxdrv , nothing happens in the terminal. Just pops down another row in the terminal so I can write another command.

What can be the problem here? Would be very grateful if someone has any tips.

Also one more question, if I remove and reinstall VirtualBox. Would this mean I would loose the saved data I have on whonix?

Thank you!

Comment: You might need to upgrade to VirtualBox version 5.2 like many others have after a Ubuntu Update.

Comment: You don't need to remove and reinstall, just install the newer version.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  So i want to install virtualbox 5.2.  I downloaded the file from virtuabox homepage. When i open the file it opens in Ubunto software pogram.  I press install, then a icon appears with a question mark and when i hoover it is says "Waiting to install" but nothing is happening here.  Any clue what is going on here? Is it because i already have a version 5.0 installed?

Comment: Is it possible to save the virtual machine and install when upgraded vitrualbox to save all the content i have on the machine.